# document.referrer referencing URLs outside the scope of my function

Tags: javascript, redirect, referrer

I'm trying to have a popup appear on my company's site if the user was redirected from multiple other URLs they own. The redirects have individually been executed via our hosting service. If I type the URL in a browser, the redirects are clearly working.

I'm at a loss, as I'm getting very unexpected results from my equation:

```
var redirectOverlayAppear = function() {

if (document.referrer == "www.abc.com" || "www.xyz.com") {

   redirectTint.style.visibility = "visible"; 

 }

}();
```

This produces my popup, but not just from the specified URLs in the function, but when I navigate from the other URLs we've specified, if I just type the new URL in the browser, or even if I navigate to Google and then type the new URL in.

If I isolate just one URL in the equation, i.e. -

```
 if (document.referrer == "www.abc.com") {

  redirectTint.style.visibility = "visible"; 

 } ...
```

Nothing happens at all.

Among other things, I'm turned around as to whether the issue is that the redirect from the host doesn't register since it's not a click event.

Is there another way to reference previous URLs besides document.referrer (I've been searching for a while, and getting nowhere)?

Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: document.referrer is a full valid URL ... not just a host ... so `http://example.com/some/path/page.html` for example

Comment: `document.referrer == "www.abc.com" || "www.xyz.com"` is not what you think it is ... it doesn't check if the referrer is one or the other ... it checks if `document.referrer == "www.abc.com"` which is false, so then it checks if `"www.xyz.com"` is "truthy" ... which it is, as a non-empty string is truthy ... this is why your condition is **always** true

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that if that way, it is not checking either or.

The if is saying if `document.referrer == "www.abc.com"` is true or if `"www.xyz.com"` is truthy. Since `"www.xyz.com"` is always truthy it will always go into the if.

```
if (document.referrer == "www.abc.com" || document.referrer == "www.xyz.com")
```